# Placing the grid along date tickmarks

Tags: r, strptime

I have the following data:

```
x=strptime(20010101:20010110)
y=1:10
z=data.frame(x,y)
```

So my data is this:

```
            x  y
1  2001-01-01  1
2  2001-01-02  2
3  2001-01-03  3
4  2001-01-04  4
5  2001-01-05  5
6  2001-01-06  6
7  2001-01-07  7
8  2001-01-08  8
9  2001-01-09  9
10 2001-01-10 10
```

When I create a plot in base using:

```
plot(x,y)
grid(NULL,NULL)
```

My vertical grid does not align with the date tick marks.  I know this seems like a pretty simple problem, but I have not found a solution to this anywhere.  Is there a way to get the vertical grid to align with the date tick marks using base that does not require me to do this:

```
abline(v=as.numeric(strptime(c(20010102,20010104,20010106,20010108,20010110),'%Y%m%d')))
```

I have a lot of plots with different dates and I would really like to automate this as much as possible, hopefully using base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abline` can extract the date ticks from your POSIXlt vector (via strptime).

```
x=strptime(20010101:20010110,format="%Y%m%d")
y=1:10

plot(x,y)
grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL)
abline(v=axis.POSIXct(1, x=pretty(x)),col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted", lwd = par("lwd"))
```

I would suggest creating your own function which would add both horizontal and vertical grids.

```
my.grid <-function(){
grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL)
abline(v=axis.POSIXct(1, x=pretty(x)),col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted", lwd =
par("lwd"))
}

plot(x,y)
my.grid()
```

Answer (score 8):

The function `axis` draws your axes, tick marks and labels, and returns the tick mark positions as a vector.

Since you have `Date` data, you need to use `axis.Date` to do this, and then use `abline` to plot the grid:

```
z=data.frame(
  x=seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), by="+1 month", length.out=10)
  y=1:10
)
plot(y~x, data=z)
abline(v=axis.Date(1, z$x), col="grey80")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this alternative!  I love how there are 80 different ways to do everything in R :)

Comment: Comman missing in data frame assignment ... z=data.frame(x=seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), by="+1 month", length.out=10), y=1:10)

Answer (score 4):

As the `?grid` help file says, "if more fine tuning is required, [you can] use `abline(h = ., v = .)` directly". It's a little bit more work, but not much, and would be easy enough to wrap up in a function if you want to use it often.

Here's one way to do it:

```
plot(x,y)
abline(v = pretty(extendrange(z$x)), 
       h = pretty(extendrange(z$y)),
       col = 'lightgrey', lty = "dotted")
points(x,y, pch=16)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how did you get information on what extendedrange does?  I wish I could accept more than one answer, I gave it to P Lapointe because he also added the function to his.

Comment: No problem.  Just check `?extendrange` to learn a bit more. It's a function used by plotting functions to determine the extents of the x- and y- axes. (Compare `plot(1:10)` and `plot(1:10, xaxs="i")` to see what I mean.)

Comment: Thanks, I kept typing `?extend_ed_range` and was wondering why I was getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the intricacies of the base plots.  But, ggplot does this effectively.

```
x <- strptime(20010101:20010110, format='%Y%m%d')
y <- 1:10
z <- data.frame(x, y)
qplot(x,y,data=z,'point')
```